# Reserve space for pseudo element before on mouse over

Tags: html, css

I want to add image to every `li`, but I would like to display it only on mouse over.
However, I want to avoid 'moving' effect, which is consequence of new  element (image) added to DOM. I tried to fix it with `visibility:hidden`, since that takes space, but without luck.

Here's the simple example, as you can see, on hovering these `li`'s, they are moving on the right.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/UQAjh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want either position the `:before` pseudo element absolutely to prevent it from entering the layout flow when shown, or create the pseudo element independently from the `:hover` state at an `opacity` of 0 and set `opacity` to 1 when hovered.

**Keeping `:before` out of layout flow**

```
ul > li:hover:before {
   /* all the other styles */
   position: absolute;
   left: 25px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/UQAjh/1/

**Creating `:before` regardless of `:hover` state**

```
ul > li:before {
   /* all the other styles */
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   opacity: 0;
}

ul > li:hover:before {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/Nda6Z/1/

Comment: Just out of interest: Which variant did you go for and why?

Comment: I'm gonna use first variant, less code :) Regardin second approach, I tried similar with visibility:hidden, but that didn't work. Opacity will do the trick, great!